# Find infimum and closure of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $$
\mathbf{A}=\left\{\frac{\mathbf{3 m}+\mathbf{2 n}}{5\mathbf{m}+7 \mathbf{n}}: \mathbf{m}, \mathbf{n} \geq \mathbf{3}\right\}
$$

Now find :

1. $inf(A)$
2. $int(A)$ , interior points
3. $cl(A)$ , closure of $A$

With euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$

We have $int(A) =\emptyset $ because $A$ is countable. also if $m$ be fixed then

$$ lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{\mathbf{3 m}+\mathbf{2 n}}{5\mathbf{m}+7 \mathbf{n}}= \frac{2}{7}$$

and if $n$ be fixed we have :

$$ lim _{m \to \infty} \frac{\mathbf{3 m}+\mathbf{2 n}}{5\mathbf{m}+7 \mathbf{n}}= \frac{3}{5}$$

Also  for $m=n $ we have :

$$ lim _{m \to \infty} \frac{\mathbf{5 m}}{12\mathbf{m}}= \frac{5}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{3m + 2n}{5m + 7n} = k$$
$$(3m + 2n) = k(5m + 7n)$$
$$(7k -2)n + (5k-3)m = 0$$
$$-\dfrac{7k-2}{5k-3}= \dfrac{m}{n} > 0$$
so $\dfrac{7k-2}{5k-3} < 0$ and $\dfrac{2}{7} \leq k \leq \dfrac{3}{5}$. You can prove that $A$ is dense in $[2/7, 3/5]$, so $inf(A) = \dfrac{2}{7}$, $int(A) =\{\}$ and $cl(A) = [2/7, 3/5]$.

Comment: Why $A$ is dense ? With Bézout's identity ? because (3,2)=1 and (7,5)=1 ?

Comment: For all $k \in [2/7, 3/5]$ and for all $\epsilon$ you can take $\dfrac{m}{n}$ such that $\left| -\dfrac{7k-2}{5k-3}-\dfrac{m}{n}\right| < \epsilon$, look that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory).