# About limit point of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, polynomials, metric-spaces

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{R} [x,y]$ are two polynomials and $g(m, n)\neq 0$ for all $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$, and $deg(f) \le deg(g) $ then can we find limit point and  intrior point of following set in $\mathbb{R} $ with euclidian metric ?

$$\{\dfrac{f(m,n)}{g(m,n)} | m,n\in \mathbb{N} \}$$

For example in special case in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117642/find-infimum-and-closure-of-a/4117683#4117683) 
We can find limit point of this set

Comment: The interior will be empty since the set is countable. To look at limit points, I think you can try fixing the first component as $m=1$, say, and then taking $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The notion of degree for these bivariate polynomials would bear clarification.  It is unclear why you hope to find an *interior* point of the set as contained in $\mathbb R$.  If $f,g$ have rational coefficients, then your set will be rational points and empty interior.